# Why does Minecraft think it's offline?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

I am currently having issues where I load Minecraft (Java), and everything is online, however when I try to play online on a server or go to my own server a message appears telling me that I am offline.

I have tried deleting and reinstalling - but every time I try to delete it, a message appears saying that Minecraft is running and it can't be deleted. This problem started happening after I accidentally unplugged my power plug for my PC.

Has anyone faced a similar issue and could help me out?

Answer (score 1):

## Quick Solution

This might not fix it, but if anyone has this issue make sure you are allowing Java Area Runtime through the Windows Firewall.

## Stop Minecraft

If Minecraft is still running and you cannot stop it by normal means, go to CMD, and enter this:

```
taskkill /im javaw.exe /f /t
```

This ends Java Area Runtime. Sometimes tasks won't stop themselves when asked, so we do it forcefully with `/f`. The `/t` is to end processes started by it, which would be Minecraft.

## How You're Getting Rid of It

You said you were "deleting" it. While this might be a simple terminology mistake, if you are deleting files do NOT do that. You should be going to your apps and having Minecraft uninstall itself.

Comment: i ment to put uninstall i've tried fire wall how do u get to CMD?

Comment: minecraft wont open all the way

Comment: You know the little windows search bar on the bottom left, just type cmd in it and hit enter.

Comment: the cmd thing doesnt work on my pc im on windows 8 if that helps

Comment: @minecrafterinthemaking for Windows 8 it should be the same, but try the updated command. Then try to do what you were doing before and see if it says Minecraft is still open. If you are still having issues, I can only assume you may have some malware infection and may want to get malwarebytes (its free), otherwise I don’t know how to help you much from there. Sorry.

Comment: i have malware bytes but dont know how to work it tho

Comment: @minecrafterinthemaking you should be able to just click the scan button in malwarebytes. Have you first made sure you allowed Java through the Windows Firewall, if so, how did you go about uninstalling Minecraft, did that work? After that if your computer still thinks Minecraft is running, then maybe you have some kinda malware infections screwing up your computer. Also, I assume you have, but you have tried **restarting your computer**? Note that shutting it down and then turning it on is **not** the same as a restart.